# How to convert void (myClass::*)() to void (*)()

Tags: c++, function, pointers, unreal-engine4

I'm currently working on a C++ project on the Unreal Engine and I can't wrap my head around this problem.

```
class A
{
public: 
    void (* array[10])();

    //Add Function to an array
    void AddFunctionToArray(void(*function)());
};

class B
{
public: 

    A a;

    //Sending a B function to A
    void SendMyFunction();
    void Foo();
};

void B::SendMyFunction()
{
   a.AddFunctionToArray(&B::Foo);
}
```

I get the error: `can't convert void (B::*)() to void (*)()`

How can I send a function pointer from one of my class to another?

Comment: You'll probably want to use `std::vector` instead of that C-style array.

Comment: `B::Foo` requires a `B` to run. Unreal Engine doesn't have a `B` so it can't call it. Make `B::Foo` `static` or make it a free function outside of `B` so that it doesn't require a `B`.

Comment: If the Unreal API provides a "closure" value that's passed back to the callback (e.g. in C APIs it's often something like `void *data`) then you can pass a pointer to a small structure containing a `B*` and a `(B::*)()`, then make the callback be a wrapper function which casts the `void *data` closure pointer back to your structure, then calls the appropriate function.  (Or more simply, bind them into a lambda object, stick that into a `std::function` object, then have the callback cast the `void *data` to the `std::function` type and call that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void (B::*)()` is a pointer to a non-static member function, while `void (*)()` is a pointer to a non-member function. There is no conversion between the two.

Making `B::Foo` static would fix this problem. However, you will have no access to instance members of `B`.

Note that using function pointers, member or non-member, is an old style of passing function objects. A more modern way is using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects, which can be constructed from a combination of an object and one of its member functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have class A execute a method from an arbitrary class X you can try this:

```
template <typename UserClass>
void A::FireMethod(UserClass* InUserObject, typename TMemFunPtrType<false, UserClass, void(int)>::Type InFunc)
{
    (InUserObject->*InFunc)(15);
}
```

In this case we're calling a function with a single int as argument. A class B could do this:

```
A* a = myAObject;
a->FireMethod(this, &B::MyMethod);
```

with

```
void B::MyMethod(int) {}
```

Hope this helps you! If you want more information, in unreal engine you can look at the AddDynamic macro in Delegate.h